# uint8_t - 8 bits guarantee

Tags: c++

How & where is it guaranteed that an `uint8_t` is 8-bits?

Digging into N3242 - "Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++", section 18.4.1 
< cstdint > synopsis says -

```
       `typedef unsigned integer type uint8_t; // optional`
```

So, in essence, a C++ standard conforming library is not needed to define `uint8_t` at all.

Update: Probably am just asking, which line of the standard says that uintN_t types are N bits?

Comment: You should probably ask yourself if the compiler *you are going to be using* implements `uint8_t` rather than make considerations about a hypothetically standards-compliant (but totally unusable for 95% of applications) compiler that you will probably never use. Just my two `uint8_t`'s...

Comment: Hint: `<cstdint>` is almost identical to a C library header. Where is that defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From C++:

> 18.4.1 Header  synopsis
>
> ...  The header defines all functions, types, and macros the same as 7.18 in the C standard.  ...

From C:

> 7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types
>
> 1 The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width
>   N , no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus,
>   int8_t denotes such a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8
>   bits.
>
> 2 The typedef name uintN_t designates an unsigned integer type with
>   width N and no padding bits. Thus, uint24_t denotes such an unsigned
>   integer type with a width of exactly 24 bits.
>
> 3 These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides
>   integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits,
>   and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement
>   representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

---

> So, in essence, a C++ standard conforming library is not needed to define uint8_t at all.

Correct. As Nikos mentioned (+1), you just need an alternative when/if the `typedef` is not present/declared.

Answer (score 3):

The `<stdint.h>`  types are defined with reference to the C99 standard.

> **C99 draft N869 §7.17.1.1/2**:
>   “The typedef name **`uint`***N*`_t` designates an unsigned integer type with width *N*. Thus,
>   `uint24_t` denotes an unsigned integer type with a width of exactly 24 bits.”

If a type is defined by `<stdint.h>`, then so are its associated macros, and if the type is not defined, then neither are its associated macros, by C99 §7.18/4.

Thus, you can use the existence or not of the macro `UINT8_MAX` (required by C99 §7.18.2.1) to check for the presence or absence of the `uint8_t` type definition.

Answer (score 1):

`uint8_t` is guaranteed to be 8 bits wide. If it doesn't exist, then obviously you can't use it. But if it's there, it's 8 bits. There's no possibility where it's provided but is not 8 bits.